# Python Combine Lists -- Retain Relative Ordering

Tags: python, list

Not sure how to get this guy done...

have:

```
L1 = [1,2,3]
L2 = [a,b,c]
```

want:

```
[1,a,2,b,3,c]
```

Comment: What should happen if the lists have different length?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
import itertools

L1 = [1,2,3]
L2 = ['a','b','c']
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.izip(L1, L2)))
```

You could use `izip_longest` with a fill value for lists of uneven length.

Comment: Same here. Persistence wins.

Answer (score 6):

Zip the lists then flatten the result:

```
Z = zip(L1, L2)
print [x for item in Z for x in item]
```

Comment: Man... I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Long Way:

Assuming both lists are the same length:

```
merged = []
for x in range(len(L1)):
    merged.append(L1[x])
    merged.append(L2[x])
```

If they aren't, take the lengths of both arrays, compare them, keep the length of the longer list. Then run the code for the range(len()) of the larger list and have an if statement in there that will run for the larger list (append only the larger list's values) after x is larger than the last index of the smaller list. This will probably require you to store each list in two different lists labeled "smaller" and "larger" or something like that after the comparison.

The Short Way:

Zip the lists.

Comment: Damn. Looks like I've been beaten to the chase as I was writing up the long way to do it as well. :-P

Comment: Also, obviously zipping the lists returns tuples, but it looks like other people have sufficiently answered what to do once you zip'em. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Zip and sum the result:

```
sum(zip(L1, L2), ())
```

Comment: Nope, zip returns list of tuples.

Answer (score 0):

While `chain`+`zip` (or `izip` on Python 2) works for this scenario, it silently drops data if the inputs have uneven length. In some cases, you want to round robin indefinitely until all inputs are drained.

For that purpose, the most general solution is the `roundrobin` recipe from [the `itertools` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    num_active = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
    while num_active:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            # Remove the iterator we just exhausted from the cycle.
            num_active -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, num_active))
```

For your input, this works:

```
list1 =  [1, 2, 3]
list2 =  ['a', 'b', 'c']

print(list(roundrobin(list1, list2)))  # Outputs [1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c']
```

But for mismatched inputs, it still works without dropping data:

```
list1 =  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2 =  ['a', 'b', 'c']

print(list(roundrobin(list1, list2)))  # Outputs [1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c', 4, 5]
```